# I want to combine multiple jquery filter and hide parent div according to inner div's name attribute

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm not expert on jquery and i have a problem about filter() method, any help?

I have a container div that involves 2 another divs as below but number of container div is dynamic.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="city" name="64">London</div>
  <div class="region" name"7">some region</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="city" name="65">Paris</div>
 <div class="region" name"8">other region</div>
</div>
 .
 .
 .
 .
<div class="container">
 <div class="city" name="165">some city</div>
 <div class="region" name"58">another region</div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is filter these div.container's according to inner div's name attribute using jquery.
I have two select boxes that have same data with name attributes of each inner div. 
when select a value at first selectbox (which is same with inner div.city's name attribute) then i want to hide all parent (.container) divs other than inner div.city's name attribute is same as what i have selected at selectbox.

I have already do this part :)

what i can't is about second select box. If i try to do same thing at second select box only one filter work. How can i combine following codes ?My jquery is below:
(#liste_tur_filter --> my first selectbox)
(#liste_il_sec_filter --> my second selectbox)

```
    <script>
    $(document).on('change','#liste_tur_filter', function(){

        filter_1_value = $('#liste_tur_filter').val();

        $('.urun_container').hide();

        $('.liste_tur')
            .filter('[name="'+ filter_1_value +'"]')
            .parent().show(); // show the filtered elements

    });
</script><!--liste türü filtresi-->

<script>
    $(document).on('change','#liste_il_sec_filter', function(){

        filter_2_value = $('#liste_il_sec_filter').val();

        $('.urun_container').hide();

        $('.sehir')
            .filter('[name="'+ filter_2_value +'"]')
            .parent().show(); // show the filtered elements

    });
</script>
```

How can i combine these? (if i can't ask my question clearly i'm sorry)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: From the selectors you have in your logic, to the markup you have provided, I'm having a hard time seeing how the two relate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set listener on both filters and so do `hide()` just once.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change','#liste_tur_filter, #liste_il_sec_filter', function(){

        var filter_1_value = $('#liste_tur_filter').val();
        var filter_2_value = $('#liste_il_sec_filter').val();

        $('.urun_container').hide();

        $('.liste_tur')
            .filter('[name=' + filter_1_value + ']')
            .parent().show();

        $('.sehir')
            .filter('[name=' + filter_2_value + ']')
            .parent().show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i couldn't understand what i should do and how is there any example about this? i'm also searching but couldn't find yet.

Comment: I have wrote the code above. The listener is set on both filters and after `hide()` both result are shown at once.

Comment: i'm sorry i have tried like this kind of something and miss your codes. But due to put **"})"** before parent().show(); your codes didn't work?Do we have add something another place?

Comment: You are right. There were extra some quotes and double quotes and brackets. I removed all. Please check again

Comment: So...i have already tried this solution is worked but it's not what i want. This solution work as "OR" means it shows **results that match with #liste_tur_filter** and  **results that match with #liste_il_sec_filter** i want to aplly **#liste_il_sec_filter* on  **#liste_tur_filter** results.

Comment: OK! now I understand your main question. I have posted a new answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

in second listener do not hide all elements again but hide those have not the name you want using `not equal` `!=` selector:

```
$(document).on('change','#liste_tur_filter', function(){
    filter_1_value = $('#liste_tur_filter').val();
    $('.urun_container').hide();
    $('.liste_tur').filter('[name='+ filter_1_value +']').parent().show();
});

$(document).on('change','#liste_il_sec_filter', function(){
    filter_2_value = $('#liste_il_sec_filter').val();
    $('.sehir').filter('[name !='+ filter_2_value +']').parent().hide()
     })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Ali Sheikhpour. i've found;

```
<script>
 $(document).on('change','#liste_tur_filter, #liste_il_sec_filter', function(){

   filter_1_value = $('#liste_tur_filter').val();
   filter_2_value = $('#liste_il_sec_filter').val();

     $('.urun_container').show();

   if(filter_1_value != null)
   $('.liste_tur').filter('[name!='+ filter_1_value +']').parent().hide();

   if(filter_2_value != null)
   $('.sehir').filter('[name!='+ filter_2_value +']').parent().hide();

           });
 </script>
```